# htaccess 301 redirect querystring to root

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm stuck trying to redirect my old posts on my wordpress blog from www.domain.com/?p=444 to just the root, this is because the posts have been removed.

This is what i have tried so far.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=[0-9]+
RewriteRule ^p$ / [L,R=301]
```

Any help would be much aprreciated.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=[0-9]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /? [L,R=301]
```

`/?` means root URL with `?` for removing existing query string removed.